# Calculating percentage within the oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

given a table that for the following commands:

```
SELECT sum(weight),type,plant FROM my_table ph 
 GROUP BY QUALITY_NUM_ID , PLANT_CONFIG_NUM_ID
```

gives :

```
   WEIGHT      |TYPE|PLANT|
---------------|---|-----|
          50310|  1|   42|
            515|  2|   42|
          25105|  1|   26|
           2335|  7|   26|
        1763525|  1|   22|
         160885|  2|   22|
         108956|  3|   22|
```

I'm having a difficulty writing a query that will calculate percentage of weight within each plant and type. So the output should look like this:

```
       WEIGHT |TYPE|PLANT|PERCENT|
---------------|---|-----|-------|
          50310|  1|   42| 99    |
            515|  2|   42| 1     |
          25105|  1|   26| 90    |
           2335|  7|   26| 10    |
        1763525|  1|   22| 86    |
         160885|  2|   22| 8     |
         108956|  3|   22| 6     |
```

Comment: For plant 2, the values should be 12.5 and 87.5.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
SELECT type, plant, sum(weight),
       (sum(weight) * 100 /
        sum(sum(weight)) over (partition by plant)
       ) as percent
FROM my_table ph 
GROUP BY QUALITY_NUM_ID, PLANT_CONFIG_NUM_ID;
```